# How to make POST to Slack's url?

Tags: json, url, post, curl, slack

I can't make simple POST to Slack's url.

I need POST like this:

`{ "text": "" }`

to url like `https://something.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Comment: Which language are you using? If you are using CURL libs can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A curl command like this will work:

```
read -r -d '' PAYLOAD << EOM
{"attachments": [{
    "text": "Hello world!"
  }]
}
EOM
curl --data-urlencode "payload=$PAYLOAD" "https://something.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: How to execute this?in browser's console on that site?

Comment: A shell console, such as the default terminal in OS X. the `read` command is a bash built-in and `curl` is installed by default. They're likely available on any linux distro as well, but you're on your own on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

First try by curl command

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."}' https://something.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

If its working , then its a piece of cake

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"text\":\"This is a line of text.\\nAnd this is another one.\"}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://something.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Its java...In which language u want solution...

First is curl command and second is its equivalent implementation in java

Comment: Linux or windows?? In linux just paste it in terminal and press enter....for windows install curl for windows